# Is there a way to setup a hotspot with a domain name rather than IP address?

Tags: arch-linux, hotspot, wireless-access-point, hostapd

Basically I've setup a hotspot and its currently being accessed through an IP address. I'd like to use a hostname instead. This is for internal use only, meaning the ODROID device which is being used to as Access Point is connected to the internet via ethernet and only a few devices will access the AP.

My setup details: Arch Linux on an ODROID U3 device, using hostapd and dhcp server.

PS: I'm quite inexperienced with network so I might be missing something obvious here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you setting up the hotspot in first place? Remember that domain names are dependent of secondary systems (like DNS's) and the hotspot can work without them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why not.

Just make an A record in your DNS hosting interface for your domain, for a subdomain pointing to the hotspot IP address.

```
A record       hotspot.yourdomain.com        PUBLIC IP ADDRESS OF HOTSPOT
```

---

Oops, actually just realised that the connecting clients would not have access to the internet DNS servers.

However, you could add the subdomain.domain and IP address to the [hosts files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on the connecting client machines, but I really doubt that would be practical for your situation.